# Fetch all id's from elastric search using query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need to fetch all id's from the given date range:

```
def search(index_name, doc_type, esClient):
try:
    res = esClient.search(index="apps-test", doc_type='app-test-logs', body = {
           "query": { 
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                    { "range": 
                       { "datetime": 
                        { "gte": "2017-07-22",
                          "lte":"2017-07-24", }}}
                 ]
               }
         }
                                                })
    print(res)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Which return me

{u'hits': {u'hits': [], u'total': 0, u'max_score': None}, u'_shards': {u'successful': 5, u'failed': 0, u'total': 5}, u'took': 41, u'timed_out': False}

What I am looking is get list of all id's between given date range.

The only datetime field for my doc is "created_on"

Answer (score 0):

> The only datetime field for my doc is "created_on"

"created_on" is the name of the field? So there should be no `"datetime"` pharase in your query. Range Query syntax uses the name of the field, not the type (by providing the name ES will recognise the type automatically). So if your field is named "created_on":

```
{
   "query": { 
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
            { "range": 
               { "created_on": 
                  { "gte": "2017-07-22",
                    "lte":"2017-07-24"
                  }
               }
            }
          ]
        }
}
```

You can also check if the format yyyy-MM-dd is the same as you used for defining the mapping of `app-test-logs` type . If not, you can use `format` parameter in range query.